# Pandas: How do I aggregate *some* of the *columns* in a Pandas' DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to aggregate columns in a Pandas' DataFrame to one, given a certain condition. The idea is to save space in a DF and aggregate some of the columns into one, provided they answer a certain condition.
An example would probably make it easier to explain:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns     # for sample data set

# load some sample data
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

# round the age to an integer for convenience
titanic['age_round'] = titanic['age'].round(0)

# crosstabulate
crtb = pd.crosstab(titanic['embark_town'], titanic['age_round'], margins=True)
crtb
```

yields:

[image]

What I want to do, for example, is to aggregate all the columns that are >= 20 (for example), to one column called '20+' and the values would be the sum of all values per row for the columns aggregated. When column headers are <20, they would remain separated and untouched.
One way to go about it is to create another column in the original DF which gives the original value of age_rounded if it's <20 and '20+' else, or use .cut, and pivot on that.

Wondering if there's a way to do it more cleverly and without creating a new column.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this specific example, I don't think you need to add a column, just update the values in the column you already have:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns     # for sample data set

# load some sample data
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

# round the age to an integer for convenience
titanic['age_round'] = titanic['age'].round(0)
titanic.loc[titanic['age_round']>=20, 'age_round'] = '20+'

# crosstabulate
crtb = pd.crosstab(titanic['embark_town'], titanic['age_round'], margins=True)
```

Is your question how to do this in general?  There are a number of different ways to aggregate data in pandas, the most standard is to use a the .groupby() construction.  crosstab is basically a shortcut of grouping by those two variables, and then calling .unstack().

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I am looking for a general solution. This solution you suggest is similar to mine in the sense that it modifies the actual column values. I was hoping there's a solution that can be applied on the column headers (which will subsequently apply an aggregation function to the actual values).

Comment: That wouldn't make much sense to do - your values are what become your column headers.  If you wait until they're the headers, you just have more work to do.